# Customer ID in email footer (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm new to programming (mainly learned front-end non-script things until now) and I have a problem I couldn't sovle despite hours of googlin & trying.

I want to display my customer's ID in the transactional e-mails (e.g. new account, order processing) so I tried adding this to email-footer.php (in the text):

```
This is the user ID: <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>
```

Also I tried something similar with the first name in the email-header.php:

```
Hello <?php $user = get_user_by( 'id', $current_user->ID ); echo $user->first_name; ?>
```

Additionally, I have this in the head of the two files (where the inline css variables are)

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo 'This is the user ID: '.$user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help. It works in some e-mails (e.g. processing order), in some it doesn't do anything (e.g. new account) and in some it adds the admin user id (e.g. order-completed, customer note).
I basically don't need the current_user but the user the e-mail gets sent to.

Comment: that is $order->billing_email

Comment: Thanks, but that works in the order mails, but in the email "New Account" it doesn't. What could I use here?